# Failing to pass a variable to Get-Content

Tags: powershell, powercli

What im trying to do:

Run a script and load the content from an XML file. I have more then one XML file and I want it to load all of the XML files and then run them in a `foreach` loop.

I don't know why, but my second `Get-Content` always comes back empty.

Here is the crucial part of the code that isn't working for me:

```bsh
[xml]$xmlist = Get-Content "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.xml"

$x = $xmlist.Test.Test1.Test2

foreach ($newxml in $x) {
    [xml]$xml1 = Get-Content $newxml
    $x2 = $xml1.Test.Testa.Testb
}
```

`$xml1` is just staying blank and nothing gets loaded into it (while in `$newxml` I have the right path each time).

The error I get:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.XmlElement'
because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\samueu\Desktop\PS Script\Untitled15.ps1:7 char:14
+ [xml]$xml1 = Get-Content $newxml
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\windows\syst....Xml.XmlElement:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Here is the XML :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test>
    <Test1>
        <Test2>
            <Filepath>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\a.xml"</Filepath>
        </Test2>
        <Test2>
            <Filepath>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\b.xml"</Filepath>
        </Test2>
        <Test2>
            <Filepath>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\c.xml"</Filepath>
        </Test2>
        <Test2>
            <Filepath>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\e.xml"</Filepath>
        </Test2>
    </Test1>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$newxml` contains an XML node, not a string or `FileInfo` object. The string representation of the XML node object is `System.Xml.XmlElement`, but no file with that name is present in the current working directory (`C:\windows\system32`).

You need to call `Get-Content` with the value of the `<Filepath>` child node:

```
[xml]$xml1 = Get-Content $newxml.Filepath
```

Comment: So how can i pass only the string? (each time different string)

Comment: Yes i did , you are saying i need to call the Get-Content with the string of the XML node: 

I got several nodes with several Strings. if ill pass '#text' it will loop each time to the same text ?

Comment: How about you go and actually *try* it, so you can see what it does?

Comment: I have done what you suggested. 

    [xml]$xml1 = Get-Content $newxml."Hello"

the $xml1 is now empty
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: Does `$newxml."Hello"` look like `$newxml.'#text'` to you?

Comment: 1st of all ... you can be nicer , if you dont wish to help those who are un experienced you should not comment.

2cnd , ive done it also with '#text' and got the same result.. (it is under quotes meaning its string and i can input whatever isnt it?

Comment: If I didn't want to help I wouldn't be here. However, I expect you to actually follow the advice I'm giving. `#text` is the literal name of the property holding the text content of an XML node. You can't just put there whatever. If `$newxml.'#text'` gives you an empty result you need to update your question with sample XML data.

Comment: Added the xml to the question

Comment: The value you're looking for is in a child node of your selected nodes. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (had holiday over here).

When trying what you have suggested im getting :

xml           Testa
---           -----
version="1.0" Testa 
When printing $x2

Comment: I think i got it... Thanks Ansgar for the help.